# ONLY my server is not able to access shares on a specific server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, http, network-share

Here is the simplest action that works on my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop:

```
$ wget mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz
--2011-12-06 21:41:16--  http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz
Resolving mercurial.selenic.com... 173.11.57.243
Connecting to mercurial.selenic.com|173.11.57.243|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3128233 (3.0M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz'

100%[===========================================================================================================================================================================>] 3,128,233   35.1K/s   in 90s     

2011-12-06 21:42:47 (34.1 KB/s) - `mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz' saved [3128233/3128233]
```

Now I try the same command on my remote hosted server running Ubuntu Server 11.10:

```
~$ wget mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz
--2011-12-06 21:45:01--  http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz
Resolving mercurial.selenic.com... 173.11.57.243
Connecting to mercurial.selenic.com|173.11.57.243|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2011-12-06 21:48:11--  (try: 2)  http://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-2.0.1.tar.gz
Connecting to mercurial.selenic.com|173.11.57.243|:80...
```

I don't understand how my server cannot access those files (any files in the target folder) while my laptop and other PCs running Windows 7 and Windows XP can access the file using any browser.

I also checked that I can access files on other domains, it works as expected.

It seems that the problem comes from the target server but why does this happen only with my remote server?

---

**UPDATE:**

Shane asked me to do ping and traceroute to help. Here are the results:

```
~$ ping selenic.com
PING selenic.com (173.11.57.241) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from waste.org (173.11.57.241): icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=139 ms
....(skipped)
64 bytes from waste.org (173.11.57.241): icmp_req=27 ttl=48 time=138 ms
^C
--- selenic.com ping statistics ---
27 packets transmitted, 27 received, 0% packet loss, time 27905ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 137.577/143.082/158.615/5.582 ms
```

So selenic.com is ok.

```
~$ ping mercurial.selenic.com
PING mercurial.selenic.com (173.11.57.243) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- mercurial.selenic.com ping statistics ---
93 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 91999ms
```

I waited long enough to to allow the server to reply.

Here are the results of the traceroute:

```
:~$ traceroute mercurial.selenic.com
traceroute to mercurial.selenic.com (173.11.57.243), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  4k1-20.vty.dedibox.fr (88.190.20.1)  0.541 ms  0.538 ms  0.536 ms
 2  6k1-4k1-po3.vty.dedibox.fr (88.190.3.5)  0.458 ms  0.468 ms  0.537 ms
 3  th2-6k-3-po7-t.intf.routers.proxad.net (212.27.50.33)  0.920 ms * *
 4  th2-crs16-1-be1009.intf.routers.proxad.net (212.27.58.30)  1.057 ms  1.054 ms  1.050 ms
 5  te0-3-0-1.336.ccr21.par04.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.164.209)  0.821 ms  1.085 ms  1.178 ms
 6  te0-1-0-4.ccr21.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.2.21)  1.019 ms te0-6-0-3.ccr21.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.39.117)  1.211 ms te0-5-0-2.ccr22.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.58.229)  1.098 ms
 7  te0-2-0-5.mpd22.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.7.33)  81.199 ms te0-6-0-2.ccr21.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.46.97)  73.731 ms te0-5-0-4.mpd21.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.43.154)  85.701 ms
 8  te0-2-0-6.ccr21.jfk07.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.1.218)  73.806 ms  73.937 ms te0-1-0-6.ccr21.jfk07.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.46.74)  79.103 ms
 9  comcast.jfk07.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.10.98)  76.372 ms comcast.jfk07.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.9.46)  79.151 ms  76.958 ms
10  pos-1-7-0-0-cr01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.87.169)  80.832 ms  80.841 ms  80.839 ms
11  pos-0-11-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.88.174)  100.456 ms  100.435 ms  101.345 ms
12  pos-0-13-0-0-ar01.roseville.mn.minn.comcast.net (68.86.94.74)  108.807 ms  109.443 ms  108.681 ms
13  te-0-1-0-0-ar01.crosstown.mn.minn.comcast.net (68.87.174.1)  132.871 ms  134.037 ms  133.451 ms
14  te-8-1-ur02.swmpls.mn.minn.comcast.net (68.86.232.98)  134.221 ms  134.209 ms  134.942 ms
15  ge-3-0-2-ten02.swmpls.mn.minn.comcast.net (68.85.167.206)  130.049 ms  129.105 ms  130.198 ms
16  c-76-113-215-129.hsd1.mn.comcast.net (76.113.215.129)  136.449 ms  160.713 ms  153.172 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Then it gives back control to me. I don't know how to interpret this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like your system is able to connect to that server on port 80.

Check if it can get to other HTTP sites.  Have you verified with your provider that the traffic isn't blocked, or that you don't need to be using a proxy server?

Comment: I should have added the other checked I did : YES the server does access other files on other servers. I tried to access files on code.google.com for example. I tried just after what I logged. Strange isn't it? I'll try to contact my server hosting provider see if it's a problem with them.

Comment: @Klaim In that case, try a `ping` and `traceroute` to that server (`mercurial.selenic.com`).

Comment: My provider tells me it's either my servver's config that is wrong or their server that blocks mine. I did ping and traceroute, ping works on selenic.com (that is another ip) but don't get anything on mercurial.selenic.com, also traceroute have a strange log on this adress. I'll post logs in the question. I'll also ask at selenic see if they do something on their side.

Comment: @Klaim Huh - seems like they might be blocking you.  My trace looks the same, but hits 173.11.57.243 (the `mercurial.selenic` server) right after the hit where yours stops, 76.113.215.129.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm thinking that as I've bought this server only this monday, maybe the specific IP is blocked by their server because of the previous owners? Anyway, I send them an email to check.

Comment: Ok I got the anwser, I'm +1 you and validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the target server admin :

> Your netblock was blocked because some spammer bot was attacking our
>   wiki from various addresses in your vicinity.

That's fixed now.

So the answer was that they blocked the IP (block).